# How can a user prescribe a different "sync" account?

Tags: feature-request, support

The main "Accounts" page on SE allows a user to "sync with oldest profile".  Is there a way to choose a different account as the source for the "sync" operation?

For example, I am registered to both *meta* and *stackoverflow*, the former being my "oldest profile" established, the latter being the one whose profile I am likely to use/update more often, and which ideally would be the one I would like to use as the source for the "sync" operation.

Thanks!